# pgrouting 2.0 package for postgresql 9.3

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, installation, ubuntu

I'm trying to install pgrouting 2.0 on a postgresql 9.3 database (with postgis 2.1).
Are there any packages on ubuntu 12.04 or do I have to install from source?
Is postgres 9.3 supported at all in this configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The packages in [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~georepublic/+archive/pgrouting) only support the default PostgreSQL version of each Ubuntu release, which is since Ubuntu 12.04 PostgreSQL 9.1.

PostgreSQL 9.3 was just released recently, so you need to try yourself if pgRouting works or not. But I don't think there should be a problem. You need to compile though.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to install pgrouting 2.0 for postgresql 9.3 on Ubuntu 13.04 by downloading the amd64 .deb file from http://packages.debian.org/sid/postgresql-9.3-pgrouting.

I installed it using `sudo dpkg -i postgresql-9.3-pgrouting_2.0.0-2_amd64.deb`

I needed to install a few dependencies, including:

- http://packages.debian.org/sid/libboost-system1.54.0
- http://packages.debian.org/sid/libboost-thread1.54.0
- http://packages.debian.org/sid/libcgal10

which I did using the same `sudo dpkg -i` command. Took about 5 minutes versus the  5+ hours I spent trying to debug `cmake` errors.