# How to install pgrouting 2.x on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, postgis-2.0

I try to install pgrouting 2.0 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS with postgresql 9.2

I have ppa in the system by 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwibber-daily/ppa`

answer:

`You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 Daily builds of Gwibber trunk
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~gwibber-daily/+archive/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: zbiór kluczy ,,/tmp/tmpO_cWbg/secring.gpg'' został utworzony
gpg: zbiór kluczy ,,/tmp/tmpO_cWbg/pubring.gpg'' został utworzony
gpg: zapytanie o klucz 72D340A3 z hkp serwera keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpO_cWbg/trustdb.gpg: baza zaufania utworzona
gpg: klucz 72D340A3: zaimportowano klucz publiczny ,,Launchpad PPA for gwibber-daily''
gpg: Ogółem przetworzonych kluczy: 1
gpg:               dołączono do zbioru: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK`

next I've typed `sudo apt-get update`

looks like everything OK, but what next?

on the [topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74315/pgrouting-2-0-package-for-postgresql-9-3) i haven't found much informations.
Thanks for answer.Tom

Answer (score 1):

Why do you add `ppa:gwibber-daily/ppa` if you want to install pgRouting?

You should be able to install pgRouting as described in the pgRouting workshop: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/installation.html#pgrouting